# cakePHP assigning var from function/method

Tags: cakephp, controller, variable-assignment, var

Here is my code:

```
class ManImportsController extends AppController {
    public $uppath;
    var $name       = 'ManImports';
    var $uses       = array ('RFupload','ManImport');
    var $helpers    = array ('Html', 'Session','Time', 'Form', 'Js', 'Javascript','DatePicker','Ajax','IrDependentArray','databaseFields','FileUpload.FileUpload', 'showFields');
    var $components = array ('FileUpload.FileUpload','Session','RequestHandler');
    var $actsAs     = array('FileUpload.FileUpload' => array(
                      'uploadDir' => $this->uppath,           // Primary Upload Path
                      'forceWebroot' => false,                // false, files upload to uploadDir
                      'fields' => array ('name' => 'name', 'size' => 'size',
                      'date' => 'date', 'created' => 'created',
                      'type' => 'type'),
                      'allowedTypes' => array ('csv' => array('application/csv'),
                      'xls' =>array('application/vnd.ms-excel'),
                      'xlsx' =>array('application/vnd.ms-excel')),
                      'required' => false,                    // true = errors when file isn't uploaded.
                      'maxFileSize' => false,                 // false to turns off maxFileSize
                      'unique' => true,                       // true will overwrite files with same name.
                      'massSave' => true,
                      'fileNameFunction' => false));          //execute the Sha1 function on a filename before saving it (default false)

    public function beforeFilter() {
       $this->uppath = $this->get_path();
    }  // end function beforeFilter

    function get_path() {
       $mach = gethostname();
       if ($mach=='my_machine_ID') {
          $path = "C:/home/files/uploads/";
       } else {
          $path = '/home/files/uploads/';
       }  // end if $mach
       return $path;
    }  // end function get_path
} // end class ManImportsController
```

The problem is getting the "uploadDir" properly assigned by properly calling the function/method "get_path".  I've tried about 4 different combination, from both cakePHP conventions and PHP OOP, but nothing has worked so far.

Do you see what I'm missing here and can you show me the right way to call this!

I have to deploy on Linux box, but need to work currently with Win7 dev machine.

Comment: Do you get any errors? I'm not sure whether it is related to your problem, but behaviors are defined in models, not in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First, $actsAs is for specifying Model behaviours. You should never have $actsAs in your controller.

Read [the doco](https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin) carefully - you're either:
a) implementing the Behaviour, via $actsAs, in your Model (in which case you don't need the component in your controller at all) or
b) if you really don't need a model and want to implement the Component instead, then you include the component in your controller, and you don't need the $actsAs at all. (Note that this is way is not recommended)

But either way, you should never have an $actsAs in your controller.

EDIT: By the way, I obviously don't know your specific requirements you have, or what version of CakePHP you're using, but [this upload plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) is far more recently updated and actively maintained than the one you're using.

Comment: Thanks! Company has us stuck on 1.3, and not allowed to update.  Don't think I can do the other thing I wanted which is shadow text in dropdown select fields, in V1.3.  Wanted that for cleaner screen.

Comment: Will move the $actAS into the model, but really been struggling with the uploader.  Might be back for more insight, if I can't get it working.

Comment: I currently get no errors and can not even get an "echo 'HELP';" out of this so not sure if it is even processing at all.  Screen is displaying fine and all the dropdowns needed propagate, but nothing when "Upload" button is clicked.  Can put all this on PasteBin if that helps!

Comment: Ah, 1.3. I don't know that I can give you any more help; I haven't actually used the plugin you're using. For 1.3 projects, I used https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload, which I found good. It's now deprecated, but by the looks of things, the plugin you're using at the  moment is effectively deprecated also (along with a lot of 1.3 plugins!)

Comment: All,  Need help getting past this file upload issue

Comment: Thanks for the ActAs info, I got past this but so long ago, I forgot how!  Thanks anyway!